# Copy range each minute (with possibility to change)

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am beginner at VBA always managed with functions to solve my problems
In this case i have online feed of market bids and offers and summary 
i want to copy each minute summary values and formats to  to the right, with some variable that will correspond with time interval between copy&paste
updated 11/06

Look at this my attempt pls[in image you can see data imoptrted with current bids and offers [Range"A4:C104"] current quote  F5 and its place in F3 
In yellow you can see 10 best (closest to current bids and offers) which i want to copy and paste every 5 min to the  right to see market trends [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9LyL.png)

```
Dim timerun



Sub copymacro()

Dim r1 As Range
Columnstart = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Set r1 = Worksheets(1).Range("i5:L17")
r1.copy
r1.Offset(0, Columnstart).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Columnstart = Columnstart + 9
Call nextrun


End Sub

Sub nextrun()
timerun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Application.OnTime timerun, "copymacro"

End Sub

Sub start()
Call nextrun
End Sub

Sub Finish()
Application.OnTime timerun, "copymacro", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Update_Quote_()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Source Requests").Range("J4:M18")

    Set r2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:d18")
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    runTime_1 = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime runTime, "RunEvent_1"
    
End Sub

Comment: Please don't add code to a comment as it's unreadable as you can see. And people are unlikely to download your file, better to add a screenshot.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do and achieve, but a start could be to wrap the code in a `For i = 1 To 60 .... Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00")) .... Next i` To get a timer to loop the copy every minute. Since we have 60 loops it will run the macro for an hour.

Comment: Thank you  !  i have an import from Exchange and i want to copy summary of it each minute to the left, otherwise it will overwrite with the new data again and again                 Sub Update_Quote_()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Source Requests").Range("I4:M18")
    Set r2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:d18")
     
   For i = 1 To 60
   
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))

Next i
End Sub             (You meant like this)

Comment: please if i need  to clear smthng out, tell me     Eng isn't my native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim timerun

Sub copymacro()

Dim r1 As Range
Columnstart = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Set r1 = Worksheets(1).Range("i5:L17")
r1.copy
r1.Offset(0, Columnstart).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Columnstart = Columnstart + 9
timerun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Application.OnTime timerun, "copymacro"


End Sub


Sub Finish()
Application.OnTime timerun, "copymacro", , False
End Sub
```

if you need copy range on a periodic basis